# How come the following CSS selectors aren't equivalent?

Tags: css

I have two identical sets of files (html + css) with just one difference between them. That slight difference produces drastically different results when I scale down and use the @media to change the layout and I don't understand how come it's not identical.

Just to clarify - there are no extra css rules or elements that could affect it.
It's from a Udemy course project, so I have the "correct" solution provided by the instructor to check. (Also the reason why I'm doing it the @media way, so I'm not looking for a more efficient solution, just looking to understand the difference please)

My part of the CSS code

```
.left.card{
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
}

.right.card{
  width: 45%;
  float: right;
}
```

[image]

Solution part of the code

```
.card {
  width: 45%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

[image]

The code pertains to two  elements
And this is what the @media part looks like

```
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }

  .card img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    /*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit*/
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

I tried setting "float:none" - didn't change anything

Thank you in advance

Comment: I advise you to read more about CSS and selectors because the *slight difference* you see is a **huge** difference in the CSS world and it has a big impact like you have noticed

Comment: @TemaniAfif Been trying to find something that would make sense + asking ChatGPT, but ChatGPT got it wrong and claimed it's the same.
I even tried separating it into 4 different selectors (in case it was a case of priorities and such), first two setting just the width, the other two just the float. Didn't help, so I'm lost as to why it's different.

Comment: another advise: stop using ChatGPT and read courses/tutorials written by real humans.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm using it as a guide when I'm lost or unsure. My primary source is the Udemy course + the mozilla devs docs. Could you point me in the right direction please? I realize I'm overlooking something fundamental, but I wouldn't be asking here if I didn't try looking for the answer beforehand.